# Error Checking and Validation using Bluetooth in Java

Tags: java, java-me

Using Bluetooth I wish to communicate between a Windows PC and a mobile phone. The PC will probably have Bluecove while the mobile comes with JSR-82.

Do I have to implement CRC and other error checking procedures in my software related to Bluetooth transmission and reception or does the underlying Stack and hardware takes care of those details?

For instance if I send a message to another device over RFCOMM/SPP I need to be certain whether the message reached the device and whether it received exactly what I sent.

How can this be implemented or does this have to be checked in software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RFCOMM is supposed to provide a reliable connection like tcp.
Data should arrive in the order it was sent, without corruption, or not at all.

Comment: Thanks, so apart from checking for connection loss of client or server, I needn't bother about low level details. What I was worried about is since the Bluetooth range(class 2 device) is around 10mts, if a device goes out of that range communication would be disrupted.

Comment: Though realizing your answer has been given years ago, could you go more into detail where the error detection is happening (or point me to some sources). It's probably not handled within the RFCOMM protocol or on the host stack level at all but within the controller stack (link layer). But how exactly?